# Determining if clicked element is inside a specific div

Tags: jquery, event-delegation

I have a series of divs with the class "addedelement" which are dynamically added.
Inside all of this layers there are more nested divs, one of them containing some images with attached events. When I click on one of this images I want to know if it is inside the LAST of those divs:

```
if($(this).is('div.addedelement:last div.contextmenu img.up'))
{
    alert('Ok');
}
```

I don't know why, but this conditional expression is fired independently of the case in which the trigger is inside the last 'elementadded' div or not. But if I try to apply a css to the element like this:

```
$('div.addedelement:last div.contextmenu img.up').css('display','none');
```

It works like a charm.
What I'm missing?
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Can you add the relevant HTML markup and click event? In addition if you can get a fiddle working on jsFiddle.net that would be even better to allow others to quickly test out possible solutions.

Comment: What do you means with LAST?

Comment: The last item of a serie.

Comment: have you tried .next() its a kind of hack but helps.... .next('Div').length != null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is using jQuery `index` method, you can select the closest parent of the image with class of `.addedelement` and pass the element to the `index` method, if the length of the cached jQuery object(-1) equals to the index of the parent element within jQuery collection then the element is the last one.

```
// define these variables outside of the event handler 
var $a = $('div.addedelement'), len = $a.length - 1; 

// within your event handler
var cur = $(this).closest('div.addedelement').get(0);
if ( $a.index(cur) === len ) {
   // last
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ga5s9/

However. if you want to register a handler only for the images within the last div element with class of `addedelement` you can code:

```
$('div.addedelement').last().find('img.up').click(function(){
   // last
})
```

Comment: Thank you! Your code works in jsfiddle but it doesn't work in my page... There must be something here that makes it fail.

Comment: @user997593 You are welcome, do you see any errors on the console?

Comment: No, the console is clear, the fact is that I have a hell of nested divs and maybe is already too deep...